# Generated a third bootable back up on a second external SSD and now the first external SSD with second bootable doesn't work

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, ssd

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a SanDisk Extreme external SSD. I decided to buy an identical second external SSD to set it up with Ubuntu 18.04 as well so I could have a back-up operating system in case my first one failed and also so I could change some of the programs I have installed.  I set up the second one exactly like I did the first one.  Now when I try to boot from the original external SSD, the GRUB menu constantly shows up and it is not being detected.  When I setup the second external SSD the first one was not plugged in so there wasn't a chance of me overwriting it. I am able to boot from the new external SSD I created.

Does anyone have any advice on what is happening?

I am using an ASUS ROG laptop with Windows 10 installed on my main internal drive.  I have made sure secure boot and fast boot are both disabled.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Does the second disk's `/etc/fstab` specify partitions by `UUID=`? They'll be different. Does the second disk's `/etc/fstab` specify partitions by `/dev/sdxx`? That'll be different, too. Did you `sudo grub-install` the second drive?

Comment: Do you have ESP - efi system partitions on external drives? Ubuntu's Ubquity installer only installs grub2's boot loader files to first ESP. Then you only have one /EFI/ubuntu folder. You can boot external from its ESP with UEFI menu and drive entry which uses /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Old bug never fixed, please add to it. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Others suggest disconnecting all other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive.